# i have a problem with software R with anova test for glm

Tags: r

Hi I would like to know the meaning of the first three columns, "Resid. Df", "Resid. Dev" and "df" and how they are calculate, on the output of anova test for glm. I put a picture of an example. Can you anyone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1v5W.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: what did you fit? if you fit glm, the residuals will depend on what is the family, can you provide the code and preferably a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

When multiple models are passed as arguments to the `anova()` function, it compares the second through n-th models to the first, or "base" model in terms of reduction of deviance.

As an example, we'll fit three generalized linear models using the Motor Trend Cars database `mtcars` and compare them with the `anova()` function.

```
m1 <- glm(am ~ mpg ,data = mtcars,family="binomial")
m2 <- glm(am ~ mpg + wt, data = mtcars,family="binomial")
m3 <- glm(am ~ mpg + wt + disp, data = mtcars,family="binomial")
anova(m1,m2,m3,test="Chisq")

> anova(m1,m2,m3,test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: am ~ mpg
Model 2: am ~ mpg + wt
Model 3: am ~ mpg + wt + disp
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1        30     29.675                          
2        29     17.184  1  12.4909 0.0004089 ***
3        28     16.858  1   0.3266 0.5676480    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```

The `Resid. Df` column lists the number of degrees of freedom remaining after accounting for the independent variables in the model, each of which consumes a degree of freedom. The `Resid. Dev` column contains the residual deviance, or the deviance left unexplained by the model. The `Df` column shows the additional of degrees of freedom consumed by a model relative to the models above it in the list. The `Deviance` column shows the incremental deviance explained by this model relative to the models above it in the list. The `Pr.(>Chi)` provides the probability that the model in a given row explains significantly more deviance than the row above it.

For our example analysis, the base model uses miles per gallon to predict whether a car has an automatic or manual transmission `am`. Adding a car's weight `wt` to the model significantly improves the explanatory power of the model over the base model with `mpg` (miles per gallon). Adding a car's displacement `disp` to the model does not add significant explanatory power to the model, because the Chi Square test is not significant at the 0.05 level.

### How is Deviance Calculated?

Deviance is calculated as the difference of log likelihoods between the fitted model and the saturated model (i.e. a model that perfectly fits the data). Note that deviance is a generalization of the concept of residual sum of squares in a linear model. Eduardo Garcia Portugués has a nice writeup of the details of math in his online book, [Notes on Predictive Modeling](https://bookdown.org/egarpor/PM-UC3M/glm-deviance.html).